# Programming in Java an iPhone app

Tags: java, iphone

What I want to do is an iPhone app. But I want to program this in **Java** : is it possible?

Because, to program an iPhone app you have to program in Swift or Objective C, but can we do it in Java?...

Comment: I never really tried it though but search for Intel Multi-OS Engine.

Comment: There are commercial products that let you do this: https://www.codenameone.com/  I think Oracle had a similar product at one time, I don't know its current status though.

Comment: Here it is: [Oracle ADF Mobile](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/oracle-brings-java-to-ios-devices-and-android-too) But investigate thoroughly because Oracle has a habit of dropping support for products if they don't have enough developers.

Comment: Questions for off site resources are off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a solution: [RoboVM](https://robovm.com). Unfortunately it has been discontinued. But still available here: https://github.com/robovm/robovm

Also you may look at: [Avian](https://readytalk.github.io/avian/) and [Intel Multi-OS Engine](https://software.intel.com/en-us/multi-os-engine)

Comment: I'm surprised you mentioned all the smaller solutions and specifically ignored [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) which is more portable, popular and has been around longer than all of the above. Arguably it's better on many other fronts...

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution https://www.codenameone.com/ which allows WORA for iOS and many other OS's including Windows UWP etc.